# How to type dictionary passing style?

Tags: typescript, typeclass, higher-kinded-types

I know that TS doesn't support higher kinded types. As an alternative for languages without HKT and typeclasses there is the dictionary passing style:

```js
const map = ({map}) => f => tx => map(f) (tx);

const arrMap = f => xs => xs.map(f);

const id = x => x;

const main = map({map: arrMap}) (id);

console.log(main([1,2,3]));
```

How can I type this in TS?

```
const map = <A, B, C>(dict: {map: (f: (x: A) => B) => (tx: C) => C}) => (f: (x: A) => B) => (tx: C) =>
  dict.map(f) (tx);

const id = <A>(x: A) => x;

const arrMap = <A, B>(f: (x: A) => B) => (xs: A[]) => xs.map(f);

map({ map: arrMap }) (id) ([1, 2, 3]); // type annotation?
```

Can avoid the type annotation? If not, how would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "map" to "mapFn", because of the error in tslint with "no-shadow-variable"

```
type IdType = (param: number) => number;
type ArrMapType = (f: IdType) => (xs: number[]) => number[];
type MapFnType = (params: { map: ArrMapType }) => (f: IdType) => (tx: number[]) => number[];

const mapFn: MapFnType = ({ map }) => f => tx => map(f)(tx);

const arrMap: ArrMapType = f => xs => xs.map(f);

const id: IdType = x => x;

const main = mapFn({ map: arrMap })(id);

console.log(main([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: I am looking for a polymorphic version.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself:

```
type map = <A, B, C>(_: { map: (_: (_: A) => B) => (_: C) => C }) =>
  (_: (_: A) => B) => (_: C) => C;

type arrMap = <A, B>(_: (_: A) => B) => (_: A[]) => B[];
type id = <A>(_: A) => A;

const map: map = dict => f => tx => dict.map(f) (tx);
const id: id = x => x;

const arrMap: arrMap = <A, B>(f: (x: A) => B) => (xs: A[]) => xs.map(f);

// type annotation seems necessary
map<number, number, number[]>({ map: arrMap }) (id) ([1,2,3]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAtghmKBeKAeAggGigIWwYQD4AKAfQC4oBvWBSs+iqdASmUNzaQ4any474oAXwFRevVu07Te-afgDcAWABQoSFDgAnbQFkEyNFlwkmksTjGSA2gF1L9levDQAlgBMjGM5SndmZzUAYwB7ADsAZ2BaMEp4RBQPN2CYgIAzaWAAD2lk1IA6BOJ0tmIclmcwqJjPSk8jXIDsoNVq6K1dAzjO-UMUDGwcEnT6bL9La2zIv3sxaaKEEsq1NQTUcIBXGAAjCG1sLd39w+297XsSGgTKHT7EUWJPFmIbAEZsACZsAGYHRSAA)